# addEventListner to multiple images

Tags: javascript

I wrote a little javascript that was supposed to change the size of all images on my web page when a user clicks on it. But I resive an error when I try to run it.

```
<script  type="text/javascript">

function changeSize(img){

var bigsize = "800"; 
var smallsize = "500"; 

  if(img.height == bigsize) img.height = smallsize;
  else img.height = bigsize;
  }
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
element.addEventListener('click',changeSize(this),false  );
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can You paste the error as well?

Comment: Also pass html code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Access your img in `changeSize` as `event.target`, also addEventListener called incorrectly, see code snippet below in details because a lot of code were updated:

Working code snippet, you could see that image border changed after clicking on image.

```js
function changeSize(event){

var bigsize = "800"; 
var smallsize = "500"; 

  if(event.target.height == bigsize) event.target.height = smallsize;
  else event.target.height = bigsize;
  }

var elements = document.getElementsByTagName ("img");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length ; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener("click", 
        changeSize, 
        false);
}
```

```css
img{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img onclick="changeSize(event)" width='30' height='40'/>

<img width='30' height='40'/>
<img width='30' height='40'/>
<img width='30' height='40'/>
```

Comment: You're adding an event listener *and* binding it in HTML with onclick..

Comment: "Your code works well" — No, it doesn't.

Comment: "pass image into your changeSize properly as in code snippet below" — Intrinsic event attributes are awful. The approach the OP was trying to take is much better.

Comment: @Quentin  Thanks for your critical comments, my answer wasn't good, you are  definitely right, i've completely updated it .

Comment: @leroy thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer completely.